# PayPal error 3005 using Magento and standard payments

Tags: paypal, magento-1.6

I've already posted this on the PayPal mts and the x.com sites but had no response.

I am looking at a clients website which is having issues taking payments using the PayPal standard payments. The Magento based site (CE 1.6.10) redirects to Paypal fine but when a customer tries to pay PayPal goes to and error page with error code 3005. I have tried using the sandbox on a development version of the site and this works fine.

The Magento site uses a secondary email address as the PayPal address and this all seems fine within the verified PayPal account.

Do you have any ideas on why this may be failing.

Comment: The error 30005 can be caused by several different reasons.  It could be getting generated due to something on the account, or something that is getting passed over.  Can you provide a link to your checkout page so that I can walk through it and see whats causing the issue, or provide what you are passing over?

Comment: Thanks Chad.  I'm not going to be able to post live urls up here but if it's any help the mts ticket I submitted is at https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/account/questions/detail/i_id/834142 where all the info you should need is.

Comment: Can you provide the ticket number, it should be in the following format... xxxxxx-xxxxxx

Comment: Sure, the ticket number is 130305-000112